# PostgreSQL several COUNT DISTINCT in same query with GROUP BY on other field

Tags: postgresql, count, group-by, distinct, postgresql-9.5

i am looking for elegant way to write PostgreSQL version of this query:

```
SELECT count(distinct a,b) / count(distinct c,d)
FROM t1
GROUP BY e;
```

It can be done via CONCAT function, but it this case i get huge performance drop.

Each count distinct can be written in this way:

```
SELECT count(*), e FROM
(SELECT a, b, e FROM t1 GROUP BY a, b, e) as tmp
GROUP BY e;
```

AND

```
SELECT count(*), e FROM
(SELECT c, d, e FROM t1 GROUP BY c, d, e) as tmp
GROUP BY e;
```

But i can't find how to combine them into one query to get final result

Here is create table to test syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
a int,
b int,
c int, 
d int, 
e int 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about elegant, but looks like it can be done in this way:

```
SELECT e, c1/c2 FROM

(SELECT count(*) as c1, e FROM
(SELECT a, b, e FROM t1 GROUP BY a, b, e) as sub1
GROUP BY e) as tmp1

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT count(*) as c2, e FROM
(SELECT c, d, e FROM t1 GROUP BY c, d, e) as sub2
GROUP BY e) as tmp2

USING (e)
```